# VirtualBox not finding Ubuntu .iso

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, iso-image

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 from their website and extracted the .zip file to a folder on my Desktop. When I go to VirtualBox to create a VM, it can't find the .iso.
There are no error messages, meaning everything installed as it should have.

Here's a screenshot of the folder:

[Screenshot of the extracted .iso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFw7R.png)

Clearly, I'm missing something, I just don't understand what it is that I'm missing. Can you explain?

Thanks, Rohail.

Comment: If there is no error message how do you know that VirtualBox cannot find the ISO?  What do the VirtualBox logs say?

Comment: Your screen shot show a folder (not a file). The file you want inside the folder should like this:  ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso  . Version number will be newer so navigate down to the file.  Make sure you downloaded correctly.

Comment: The ISO you download from the Ubuntu website should not be unpacked to be used as a CD/install-media for VirtualBox. It should also download directly as an ISO, and not as a .zip file. Make sure you get the correct image.

Comment: @John, there's no .iso, that's my issue

Answer (score 0):

> there's no .iso, that's my issue

Before you start, run a full scan with Windows 10 Defender and ensure Smart Screen is enabled.

Yes, there is an ISO file. Go to Ubuntu.com and to Desktop Downloads.

That page has a description and link to Download. Click on the green button and download the actual ISO file. It is easy but will take some time depending on your internet speed.

Once you have downloaded and save the ISO.

(ubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso)

Open Virtual Box, make a new machine, machine type = Ubuntu or Linux,and point the setup dialogue to the ISO you saved.

VBOX will start installing the virtual Ubuntu machine.

(NOTE:   Make sure before you start that Hardware Virtualization is enabled in BIOS on your physical machine).

You may wish to follow the WIKI step by step article for installing Ubuntu in VBOX.

[WIKI How to install Ubuntu](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox)

[image]

Comment: that's exactly how I did it. A Zip file is downloaded, I extracted it to a destination in my Desktop. The screenshot I provided is the end result. [This isn't the first time I've downloaded .ISOs and created VMs] Which is why I'm so confused. This isn't normal.. Could there be any other issues? [Hardware Virtualisation is enabled/not the problem here]

Comment: Download and ensure you know where the ISO file is. Since you indicate you have other VMs, I assume Hardware Virtualization is enabled. Make sure the download folder contains the ISO file (about 2.1 GB in size) and create a new VBOX virtual machine from this ISO file. It should work the way it always did. You might uninstall VBOX, restart, and install the same or newer version first.

Comment: Still no success. Tried Ubuntu 18.04 and that had the same issue. VirtualBox doesn't find the .ISO. This means that there's some internal issue? I downloaded Ubuntu 10 and that came on just fine.

Comment: There may be something wrong with your VBOX install or something wrong with Windows. I have done several ISO installs as I describe and they all work. Consider removing VBOX, do a Windows 10 Repair Install, restart, install VBOX and try again.

Comment: Follow up: At some cost of time I downloaded the ISO I pointed to in my Answer. Downloaded fine as an ISO (not a folder).  I installed VBOX 6.122 and installed it. I ran it, and created the VHD file and it found the ISO just fine. I could not finish because the machine is a Hyper-V machine, but VBOX was happy with all the files.  Follow this WIKI article.:  https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

Comment: probably some issue with the browser or there's some malware. I've never seen such an issue. I always get the ISO file

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same head scratching activity.

It turned out because I had run virtualbox as another admin user, all of the menus were defaulting to the admin user's downloads folder (which was empty). The .iso that I downloaded was of course in my user's download folder.

Hope this might help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox can use ISO files from any location:
When you click the CD button on the storage window for the new VM, a Virtual Box Question popup asks whether to choose a disk. When you do, then VirtualBox Medium window opens.

You need to press the "Add" button top left in the VirtualBox Medium window to open a file chooser dialog where you can go to any directory including your desktop.